# Parent is executing before child process, how to force opposite through semaphores?

Tags: c, memory, fork, semaphore, shared

I am having trouble using shared memory, semaphores and forks in Unix C. My semaphores are not posix. 
I create a pointer to shared memory 2*sizeof(float).
I initialize the value of my semaphore to 2 with semctl.
I do a fork() in a for loop (i<2). 
In the child processes (if fork() == 0) each child does a p operation on the semaphore (-1), writes to shared memory then does a v operation (+1) then exits. The Parent process does a p operation (-2) on the semaphore, reads the entirety of the shared memory segment(with a for loop) and does a v operation (+2). He waits on the child processes before exiting to avoid zombies.
The problem i have in output is that i get :

```
 Parent reading 0
 Parent reading 1
 Parent reading 0
 Parent reading 1
 Child writing 0
 Child writing 1
```

When what i should be getting is :

```
 Child writing 0
 Child writing 1
 Parent reading 0
 Parent reading 1
```

I have tried initializing my semaphore to 1 instead of 2 but that just stalls the program since the semaphore will never have a value of two and thus the parent process will never read.

If what i have understood about semaphores is correct, the fact that i initialize it to 2 means that the parent process can directly read even though none of the children have written anything. How can i resolve this problem?

EDIT: I added a simplified version of my code after request, i have removed error checking, and waiting for children to reduce length.

```
/** OPEN MEMORY **/

int shmid1 = shmget(1990, (size),  IPC_CREAT | 0666 ); 

float * shmPt = (float*)shmat(shmid1, NULL, 0);    

/** CREATE INITIALIZE SEMAPHORE **/   

semun1.val = 2;

int semid = semget(1991, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT)

semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, semun1 )


  /**  CREATE PROCESSES **/
  for ( ii = 0; ii < 2; ++ii) {
    if ((p = fork()) == 0) {

      int semid = semget(1991, 1, 0666);

      struct sembuf p_buf;

      p_buf.sem_num = 0;p_buf.sem_op = -1;p_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
      /** LOCK **/ 
      semop(semid, &p_buf,1);
      /** WRITE **/
      shmPt[ii] = RandomFloat;

      v_buf.sem_num = 0;v_buf.sem_op = 1;v_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
      /** UNLOCK **/
      semop(semid, &v_buf,1) 

      exit(0);
    }
    else {

      int semid = semget(1991, 1, 0666);

      struct sembuf p_buf;

      p_buf.sem_num = 0;p_buf.sem_op = -2;p_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
      /** LOCK **/ 
      semop(semid, &p_buf,1);
      /** READ **/
      for(int j =0;j<2;j++) tabFloat[j] = shmPt[j];

      v_buf.sem_num = 0;v_buf.sem_op = 2;v_buf.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO;
      /** UNLOCK **/
      semop(semid, &v_buf,1) 

    }
}
```

EDIT : 
My ultimate goal is to have 24 children writing one by one into a shared memory segment of the same size and only when it is full, then the parent can read everything and process the information. On top of that all of this needs to be in a while loop (imagine 24 cars that keep generating random times everytime they complete a lap until the first car has finished 50 laps)

Comment: Instead of _describing_ the code, why not _show_ it to us? It will be much easer to see and understand what you do then.

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, why not just post your code?  (In a simplified form if necessary.)

Comment: I have added simplified code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mis-using semaphores.  The general idea is that a semaphore counts "how many entities (threads, whatever) are allowed to use this data right now".  By starting the count at 2, you're saying "two threads may use this now".  Semaphores do not say *which* entities, nor *how* (read vs write), only *how many*.  For example, semaphores can to be used to count the number of retrievable items in a producer/consumer queue: the producer increments and the consumer decrements.  (Of course, semaphores come in all kinds of expanded flavors; since you say these are "not POSIX", but not what they *are*, it's hard to generalize much more.)

One way to make this work as described—but of course, actual code tends to vary from descriptions—is to start the semaphore count at 0, fork a child, have the child write without looking at the semaphore count, fork another child, have that child also write without looking at the semaphore count, and then have the parent wait on the semaphore (P).  That is, the semaphore says "none shall pass" but the children don't actually look at it.  Then, the two children each do V operations (+1 in each).  Once the semaphore has gone to 1, the parent starts: he can then find at least one (but perhaps only one) child-result.  The parent can do another P immediately if he needs to have both results.

(More generally, though, you may want reader/writer locks or mutexes and condition variables.  If you have POSIX threads, see `pthread_cond_init()`, `pthread_cond_wait()`, `pthread_cond_signal()`, `pthread_mutex_init()`, etc.)

---

Aha, from the comment and question-edit, I see that you're using the wretched System V shared memory and semaphore interface.

- Are you really stuck with that?  The POSIX thread stuff is nicer, in my opinion (and generally lighter-weight).
- How do you intend to organize your shared-memory?  You may get less lock-contention if each car has its own lap times region, shared only with the display thread/proc: there's one single producer (the car) and one single consumer (display thread/proc), but 24 such locks (one per car).  If all cars share one shared-memory region with the display thread/proc, you need only one lock, but it's much more active.  Which one is "better" depends on what you are doing.
- And, if you want to wait for "some car to finish 50 laps", consider having each car have its own private (or possibly shared-with-display) counter, and one counting semaphore for "number of cars that have hit 50 laps".  Each car simply counts up and upon reaching 50, increments the counting semaphore (once) too.

---

Final (I hope) edit: after fixing smaller problems, the last remaining one was the use of `SEM_UNDO` in each child process, which would do a V (of +1) to signal "data produced and all done" and then `exit`.  `SEM_UNDO` records a balancing adjustment value that is applied on process exit, so the semaphore would count up, but then immediately count right back down, leaving the parent waiting for another V that would never occur.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but my ultimate goal is to have 24 children writing one by one into a shared memory segment of the same size and only when it is full, then the parent can read everything and process the information. On top of that all of this needs to be in a while loop (imagine 24 cars that keep generating random times everytime they complete a lap until the first car has finish 50 laps).

Comment: Yes i'm afraid i'm stuck with that. When i fork in the for loop 24 times, i pass 'i' as a parameter to each child process and each one writes in shared memory at a different place. So process 0 is writing to shmPt[0] and so forth. I just want all 24 to write one by one and then the consumer to read EVERYTHING in one go after all the children have written and to loop all that as many times as necessary and i need a way to do this with semaphores.

Comment: Btw each car already has its private lap counter and after each lap i sort the array to find the fastest car and check its lap counter to compare with the MAXLAPS constant in the while loop in main.

Comment: In that case, the parent just needs to wait until at least one child has counted (privately) to 50 and then incremented the (single) "child is done" counting semaphore that is 0 before any fork(); or, it needs to wait until all children have counted (privately) to 50 and incremented their "child is done" semaphores.  For the former, parent does one P() on the counting semaphore, and children each do one V(); for the latter, parent does 24 P()s.  But, if you're fork()ing, you can just wait() instead of using the counting semaphore in the first place.

Comment: So if i initialise the sem to 0 and each child only does a v operation (+1) once they've finished writing and the parent only does a p operation (-24) to read it should work?

Comment: Yes, provided the underlying implementation takes "P(-24)" to mean "wait for counter >= 24, then subtract 24".  (The man page implies so, but I'm never entirely sure about the SysV stuff from one machine to another.)  (But if you're going to `wait` for each child to exit and the children do that immediately upon completing 50 laps, that removes the need for the counting semaphore.)

Comment: Thank your for your help but i just tried exactly that and the parent hangs right before the -24 even though no children have written yet. Should i do a semctl GETVAL right before the semop to check if its value is 24? I think not since it would not be an atomic operation?

Comment: Right, not-atomic.  But, for debugging, you might consider doing that anyway, and also having the parent use `IPC_NOWAIT` and if the operation fails with `EAGAIN`, check the actual value, `sleep` a bit, and loop, just to see what's happening with the semaphore's underlying count as child processes do their thing.

Comment: I did as suggested. The value of the semaphore starts at 0, the child writes, it increments to 1, i put a sleep(1) in the parent and then a getval,and then the getval returns 0. How is this possible? It goes from 0 to 1 to 0 with only one semop v operation being executed ?

Comment: OK, this is getting a little far afield, but having the man page in front of me, I see: "If SEM_UNDO is specified, the semaphore's adjust on exit value is decremented by sem_op's value."  Your code does set `SEM_UNDO` so I suspect this is what is biting you here.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, i swapped with IPC_NOWAIT and it no longer hangs and doesn't decrement either. However the parent still insists on reading before the child has written anything so i am getting  : child writes, sem = 1, parent sleeps,parent tries to read and fails, child writes, parent successfully reads. If you wish to post an official answer i will gratefully accept it instead of commenting here.

Comment: Ignore that last sentence , i didn't realise it was you sorry :) Thanks again